# How do i make countdown timer toggle between different durations automatically?

Tags: flutter

I want to create a timer thats for fitness app. So,  I need the timer to begin with "3,2,1".. then it switches to a countdown of 40 seconds. Once the 40 seconds is up, it switches to a 10 second timer automatically. This process repeats for X number of sets as it is for fitness app.

This is my code below. it works fine for normal start and stop. but i am unable/clueless on how to make it automatically repeat to a time countdown that i want.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

class EachCardPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _EachCardPageState createState() => _EachCardPageState();
}

class _EachCardPageState extends State<EachCardPage>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController controller;
  bool isExercising;
  String get timerString {
    Duration duration = controller.duration * controller.value;
    return '${duration.inMinutes}:${(duration.inSeconds % 60).toString().padLeft(2, '0')}';
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    isExercising = false;
    controller = AnimationController(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(seconds: 5),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.green,
      body: AnimatedBuilder(
          animation: controller,
          builder: (context, child) {
            return Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Color(0xFF2D3653),
                    height:
                        controller.value * MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  ),
                ),
                Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Expanded(
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                          child: AspectRatio(
                            aspectRatio: 1.0,
                            child: Stack(
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Positioned.fill(
                                  child: CustomPaint(
                                      painter: CustomTimerPainter(
                                    animation: controller,
                                    backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                                    color: Colors.blue,
                                  )),
                                ),
                                Align(
                                  alignment: FractionalOffset.center,
                                  child: Column(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Text(
                                        "Count Down Timer",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 20.0,
                                            color: Colors.white),
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        timerString,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 112.0,
                                            color: Colors.white),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      AnimatedBuilder(
                          animation: controller,
                          builder: (context, child) {
                            return FloatingActionButton.extended(
                                onPressed: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    isExercising = true;
                                  });
                                  if (controller.isAnimating) {
                                    controller.stop();
                                  } else {
                                    controller.reverse(
                                        from: controller.value == 0.0
                                            ? 1.0
                                            : controller.value);
                                  }
                                },
                                icon: Icon(controller.isAnimating
                                    ? Icons.pause
                                    : Icons.play_arrow),
                                label: Text(
                                    controller.isAnimating ? "Pause" : "Play"));
                          }),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}

class CustomTimerPainter extends CustomPainter {
  CustomTimerPainter({
    this.animation,
    this.backgroundColor,
    this.color,
  }) : super(repaint: animation);

  final Animation<double> animation;
  final Color backgroundColor, color;

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = backgroundColor
      ..strokeWidth = 10.0
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.butt
      ..style = PaintingStyle.stroke;

    canvas.drawCircle(size.center(Offset.zero), size.width / 2.0, paint);
    paint.color = color;
    double progress = (1.0 - animation.value) * 2 * math.pi;
    canvas.drawArc(Offset.zero & size, math.pi * 1.5, -progress, false, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomTimerPainter old) {
    return animation.value != old.animation.value ||
        color != old.color ||
        backgroundColor != old.backgroundColor;
  }
}
```

Comment: It's likely that this would be easier to achieve with 3 different timers and trigger each other and reset once they are done. As a side note, you've pasted a lot of code and it's not really relevant for your issue which is purely about timers. Being concise and to the point is the best way to get quality answers on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @JoãoSoares sorry, its my first time asking on here. So you suggest using 3 different timers and switching between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution with just one timer. You should be able to adapt this to the needs of your app:

```
class TimersIssue extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _TimersIssueState createState() => _TimersIssueState();
}

class _TimersIssueState extends State<TimersIssue> {
  Timer _countdownTimer;
  String displayCountdown = '0';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Start'),
            onPressed: () => runTimer(3),
          ),
          RaisedButton(
            child: Text('Reset'),
            onPressed: resetTimer,
          ),
          Text(displayCountdown)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void runTimer(int seconds){
    _countdownTimer = Timer.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (timer){
      setState(() {
        displayCountdown = (seconds-timer.tick+1).toString();
      });
      if(timer.tick == seconds){
        _countdownTimer.cancel();
        nextTimer(seconds);
      }
    });
  }

  void nextTimer(int seconds){
    switch(seconds){
      case 3:
        runTimer(30);
        break;
      case 40:
        runTimer(10);
        break;
      case 10:
        runTimer(40);
    }
  }

  void resetTimer(){
    _countdownTimer.cancel();
    setState(() {
      displayCountdown = '0';
    });
  }
}
```